# Проверка списка на пустоту

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if

в моем коде функция

```
result = client.get_active_orders('ETH-BTC')['SELL']
print(result)
```

выдает пустой список `[]`.

Может выдать и не пустой список, если имеются активные ордера.

Вопрос: как, с помощью `if` задать, чтобы дальнейший код выполнялся, когда список пуст?

Я пробую:

```
result = client.get_active_orders('ETH-BTC')['SELL']
if (result) == False:
    print(result)
```

с помощью `print` я проверяю, будет ли дальше выполнятся код. По моему мнению должно напечататься `"[]"`. Но ничего не печатается. Значит блок `if` у меня неверный?

Comment: Может посмотреть в сторону оператора EMPTY, хотя бы для 1 элемента массива?

Comment: В Python нет такого оператора.

Comment: к чему упоминать криптовалюту в таком базовом вопросе? Не могу понять в чём развод.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53513/14227417

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Пустой список не может быть ложным.

Попробуйте вот так

```
if not result:
   print(True)
```

Comment: Как раз в булевом контексте, как ваш идиоматичный пример кода показывает, пустая коллекция является falsy (["objects \[that are\]  considered false"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)). При этом коллекция конечно не равна False объекту. [What is Truthy and Falsy in python? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/4279)

Answer (score 4):

*// Варианты ниже приведены для примера и вместо них лучше использовать `if result` и `if not result`*

Добавлю еще варианты проверки через `bool` (**эти варианты лучше не использовать**):

```
if bool(result) is False:
    print(result)

if bool(result) == False:
    print(result)

if not bool(result):
    print(result)
```

Как это работает просто понять если вывести:

```
print(bool([]))  # False
print(bool([1, 2, 3]))  # True
```

Comment: можно упомянуть, что ни один из этих вариантов не стоит использовать (идиоматично: `if not result:`)

Answer (score -2):

```
if len(result) == 0:
    print(result)
```

Такой код будет выполняться только если список пуст. Проверка на истинность не проверяет размер массива.

Comment: Лучше так не делать.
Тут объясняется почему: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43476778

Comment: Информация, является устаревшей проблема исправлена и проверка sequence элемента на предмет его длинны является верной, не забывайте дзен python, то что явное лучше не явного