# Как упростить код? Как уменьшить количество if используемых для вывода трёхчлена

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Код:

```
import sys
a,b,c = input().split()
data = {
    "a" : int(a),
    "b" : int(b),
    "c" : int(c),
}
if data["a"] == 0:
    del(data["a"])
if data["b"] == 0:
    del(data["b"])
if data["c"] == 0:
    del(data["c"])
if len(data)==0:
    print("0")
    sys.exit()
for i in data.keys():
    if data[i] == 1:
        if "b" == i:
            data[i] = "x"
        if "c" == i:
            data[i] = "y"
    if data[i] == -1:
        if "b" == i:
            data[i] = "-x"
        if "c" == i:
            data[i] = "-y"
    else:
        if i == "b":
            if data[i] != "x":
                data[i] = "%sx" % data[i]
        if i == "c":
            if data[i] != "y":
                data[i] = "%sy" % data[i]

a = b = c = ""
for i in data.keys():
    if i == "a":
        a += "%s+" % data[i]
    if i == "b":
        b += "%s+" % data[i]
    if i == "c":
        c += data[i]
string = a+b+c
string = list(string)
i = 0
while i < len(string)-1:
    if string[i] == "+"  and string[i+1] == "-":
        del(string[i])
    i+=1
if string[len(string)-1] == "+":
    del(string[len(string)-1])
if "" == ''.join(string):
    print('0')
else:
    print(''.join(string))
```

Задача: 
     Школьная алгебра
    (Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб Сложность: 27%)

```
Трёхчлен a + bx + сy от двух переменных x и y однозначно определяется коэффициентами a, b и c. Написать программу, которая по заданным a, b и c выводит соответствующий трёхчлен, записанный с использованием алгебраических соглашений:

    1.коэффициент при члене, содержащем переменную, опускается, если его модуль равен единице;
    2.член, коэффициент при котором равен нулю, опускается (кроме случая, когда все коэффициенты равны нулю, тогда трехчлен состоит из одной цифры 0);
    3.знак "+" опускается, если он предшествует отрицательному коэффициенту;
    4.знак "+" опускается, если он стоит в начале выражения (так называемый унарный плюс);
    5.знак умножения между коэффициентом и переменной опускается.

При этом запрещено менять местами члены.


Во входном файле INPUT.TXT через пробел записаны целые коэффициенты a, b и с, каждое из которых не превосходит 30000 по абсолютной величине.

Выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT должен содержать трехчлен, записанный с использованием алгебраических соглашений.
```

Пример:

`0 2 -1`        -> `2x-y`
`3 0 -2`        -> `3-2y`

В коде у меня много условных операторов. Как уменьшить их кол-во? И как сделать код красивым?

Comment: Переместите и код, и задачу прямо в текст вопроса без ссылок на сторонние ресурсы

Comment: @andreymal исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В коде у меня много условных операторов. Как уменьшить их кол-во?

Можно для каждого правила по одному/два `if` использовать в декларативном стиле:

```
def format_polynom(*coeffs, vars=("", "x", "y")):
    return (
        "".join(
          # VVV rule #3       VVV rule #1               VVV rule #3   rule #5 VVV
          ("{:+}".format(c) if abs(c) != 1 or not v else "-" if c < 0 else "+") + v
          if c  # rule #2
          else ""
          for c, v in zip(coeffs, vars)
        ).lstrip("+")  # rule #4
        or "0"  # rule #2
    )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
def format_polynom(*coeffs, vars=("", "x", "y")):
    return (
        "".join(
            ("-" if c < 0 else "+")  # sign
            + (str(abs(c)) if abs(c) != 1 or not v else "")  # magnitude
            + v  # variable name
            if c
            else ""  # rule #2
            for c, v in zip(coeffs, vars)
        ).lstrip("+")  # rule #4
        or "0"  # rule #2
    )  
    
from browser import document
@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    coeffs = [int(document[c].value) for c in 'abc']
    print(*coeffs, '->', format_polynom(*coeffs))
on_click('dummy on start')    
</script><div><label for="a">a&nbsp;=</label>&nbsp;<input id="a" value="3"></div><div><label for="b">b&nbsp;=</label>&nbsp;<input id="b" value="0"></div><div><label for="c">c&nbsp;=</label>&nbsp;<input id="c" value="-2"></div><button id="mybutton">Форматировать трёхчлен</button></body>
```

Пример:

```
>>> format_polynom(0, -1, 2)
'-x+2y'
>>> format_polynom(3, 0, -2)
'3-2y'
```

Все интересные случаи можно перебрать, используя [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

for coeffs in product(range(-2, 3), repeat=3):
    print(*coeffs, "->", format_polynom(*coeffs))
```

#### [Результат](https://ideone.com/5S8etI)

```
-2 -2 -2 -> -2-2x-2y
-2 -2 -1 -> -2-2x-y
-2 -2 0 -> -2-2x
-2 -2 1 -> -2-2x+y
-2 -2 2 -> -2-2x+2y
-2 -1 -2 -> -2-x-2y
-2 -1 -1 -> -2-x-y
-2 -1 0 -> -2-x
-2 -1 1 -> -2-x+y
-2 -1 2 -> -2-x+2y
-2 0 -2 -> -2-2y
-2 0 -1 -> -2-y
-2 0 0 -> -2
-2 0 1 -> -2+y
-2 0 2 -> -2+2y
-2 1 -2 -> -2+x-2y
-2 1 -1 -> -2+x-y
-2 1 0 -> -2+x
-2 1 1 -> -2+x+y
-2 1 2 -> -2+x+2y
-2 2 -2 -> -2+2x-2y
-2 2 -1 -> -2+2x-y
-2 2 0 -> -2+2x
-2 2 1 -> -2+2x+y
-2 2 2 -> -2+2x+2y
-1 -2 -2 -> -1-2x-2y
-1 -2 -1 -> -1-2x-y
-1 -2 0 -> -1-2x
-1 -2 1 -> -1-2x+y
-1 -2 2 -> -1-2x+2y
-1 -1 -2 -> -1-x-2y
-1 -1 -1 -> -1-x-y
-1 -1 0 -> -1-x
-1 -1 1 -> -1-x+y
-1 -1 2 -> -1-x+2y
-1 0 -2 -> -1-2y
-1 0 -1 -> -1-y
-1 0 0 -> -1
-1 0 1 -> -1+y
-1 0 2 -> -1+2y
-1 1 -2 -> -1+x-2y
-1 1 -1 -> -1+x-y
-1 1 0 -> -1+x
-1 1 1 -> -1+x+y
-1 1 2 -> -1+x+2y
-1 2 -2 -> -1+2x-2y
-1 2 -1 -> -1+2x-y
-1 2 0 -> -1+2x
-1 2 1 -> -1+2x+y
-1 2 2 -> -1+2x+2y
0 -2 -2 -> -2x-2y
0 -2 -1 -> -2x-y
0 -2 0 -> -2x
0 -2 1 -> -2x+y
0 -2 2 -> -2x+2y
0 -1 -2 -> -x-2y
0 -1 -1 -> -x-y
0 -1 0 -> -x
0 -1 1 -> -x+y
0 -1 2 -> -x+2y
0 0 -2 -> -2y
0 0 -1 -> -y
0 0 0 -> 0
0 0 1 -> y
0 0 2 -> 2y
0 1 -2 -> x-2y
0 1 -1 -> x-y
0 1 0 -> x
0 1 1 -> x+y
0 1 2 -> x+2y
0 2 -2 -> 2x-2y
0 2 -1 -> 2x-y
0 2 0 -> 2x
0 2 1 -> 2x+y
0 2 2 -> 2x+2y
1 -2 -2 -> 1-2x-2y
1 -2 -1 -> 1-2x-y
1 -2 0 -> 1-2x
1 -2 1 -> 1-2x+y
1 -2 2 -> 1-2x+2y
1 -1 -2 -> 1-x-2y
1 -1 -1 -> 1-x-y
1 -1 0 -> 1-x
1 -1 1 -> 1-x+y
1 -1 2 -> 1-x+2y
1 0 -2 -> 1-2y
1 0 -1 -> 1-y
1 0 0 -> 1
1 0 1 -> 1+y
1 0 2 -> 1+2y
1 1 -2 -> 1+x-2y
1 1 -1 -> 1+x-y
1 1 0 -> 1+x
1 1 1 -> 1+x+y
1 1 2 -> 1+x+2y
1 2 -2 -> 1+2x-2y
1 2 -1 -> 1+2x-y
1 2 0 -> 1+2x
1 2 1 -> 1+2x+y
1 2 2 -> 1+2x+2y
2 -2 -2 -> 2-2x-2y
2 -2 -1 -> 2-2x-y
2 -2 0 -> 2-2x
2 -2 1 -> 2-2x+y
2 -2 2 -> 2-2x+2y
2 -1 -2 -> 2-x-2y
2 -1 -1 -> 2-x-y
2 -1 0 -> 2-x
2 -1 1 -> 2-x+y
2 -1 2 -> 2-x+2y
2 0 -2 -> 2-2y
2 0 -1 -> 2-y
2 0 0 -> 2
2 0 1 -> 2+y
2 0 2 -> 2+2y
2 1 -2 -> 2+x-2y
2 1 -1 -> 2+x-y
2 1 0 -> 2+x
2 1 1 -> 2+x+y
2 1 2 -> 2+x+2y
2 2 -2 -> 2+2x-2y
2 2 -1 -> 2+2x-y
2 2 0 -> 2+2x
2 2 1 -> 2+2x+y
2 2 2 -> 2+2x+2y
```

Может легче для понимания вариант, который каждый член представляет как *знак* плюс *абсолютная величина* плюс *имя переменной*:

```
def format_polynom(*coeffs, vars=("", "x", "y")):
    return (
        "".join(
            ("-" if c < 0 else "+")  # sign
            + (str(abs(c)) if abs(c) != 1 or not v else "")  # magnitude
            + v  # variable name
            if c
            else ""  # rule #2
            for c, v in zip(coeffs, vars)
        ).lstrip("+")  # rule #4
        or "0"  # rule #2
    )
```

Вывод идентичен первому варианту.

Comment: А что означает  `str(abs(c)) if abs(c) != 1 or not v else "" `  ?

Comment: `a if b else c`? Конкретный пример, это реализация правила №1

Comment: а зачаем `or not v ` ? Это как?

Comment: @AminevTimur: чтобы определить пустое имя переменной или нет. [Проверка списка на пустоту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/809586/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо (дващды в вашем коде)

```
for i in data.keys():
```

можно писать просто

```
for i in data:
```

и вместо

```
if data["a"] == 0:
    del(data["a"])

if data["b"] == 0:
    del(data["b"])
if data["c"] == 0:
    del(data["c"])
```

можно писать

```
for char in "abc":
    if data[char] == 0:
        del(data[char])
```

Стиль

```
if "b" == i:
```

старомодный (был для безопасности - `=` вместо правильного `==`) - и не только в Пытоне), пишите просто и более понятно

```
if i == "b":
```

Вместо

```
while i < len(string)-1:
    if string[i] == "+"  and string[i+1] == "-":
        del(string[i])
    i+=1
```

можно более ясно писать

```
for i, __ in enumerate(string):
    if string[i] == "+"  and string[i+1] == "-":
        del(string[i])
```

но эта ваша часть *и так неправильна* - вы в цикле изменяете этот же список, который вы проходите!

Comment: А как удалять элементы из списка?

Comment: Одна возможность не удалять, а создать новый пустой список (строку), в который вы будете подходящие элементы (знаки) прибавлять.